# скачать android sdk без android studio

Tags: android, android-sdk

Где скачать android sdk без android studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Перейти по [ссылке](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOEbd.png) на официальный сайт.
- Внизу страницы найти блок "Get just the command line tools" (отмечен
  красной стрелкой)
- Чуть ниже в списке выбрать нужную Вам платформу (выделено красной
  рамкой) и клинуть по ссылке справа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Например, [тут](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) в самом низу страницы.